# Parameterising v-model in a Vue component

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

I've written a small component to abstract some repeated HTML:

```
<template>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="desc">{{label}}</label>
    <input id="desc" readonly type="text" class="form-control input-sm"
           v-model={{v_model}}/>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: 'HelloWorld',
  props: {
    label: String,
    v_model: String
  }
}
</script>

<style scoped>
</style>
```

This gives the error:

```
Error compiling template: 

<div class="form-group"> 
  <label for="desc">{{label}}</label>
  <input id="desc" readonly type="text" class="form-control input-sm"
         v-model={{v_model}}/> </div>
- invalid expression: Unexpected token { in 

  {{v_model}}/

Raw expression: v-model="{{v_model}}/"
```

I'm expecting that things assigned to `v-...` attributes will need to be done in some other way, but I don't yet know how.

Comment: It should be `v-model="v_model"`

Comment: @ittus, Thanks, but no, I want v_model to hold a *reference* to the model, not to *be* the model.

Answer (score 0):

Solution was:

```
<template>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="desc">{{label}}</label>
    <input id="desc" type="text" class="form-control input-sm"
           v-bind:value="value"
           v-on:input="$emit('input', $event.target.value)"
    />
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: 'FormGroup',
  props: {
    label: String,
    value: String
  },
  data: function() {
    return {
    }
  }
}
</script>

<style scoped>
</style>
```

Comment: I don't understand.  `value` here looks to be the model not a reference to the model.  If it's a reference to the model then what is the actual model? And how does `$emit('input', $event.target.value)` update that model? (scratching head)

Comment: @RobC I hadn't realised that if I sent a property called value into Form group, it would refer to the data *outside".  i.e. The input could change the passed property and so I no longer needed a reference.

Comment: I understand, kinda solves the root issue a different way without needing indirection.  Thanks.